# Is a harpy's luring song an action or a bonus action?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

When a harpy uses its Luring Song, is it an action or a bonus action? In the MM it states:

> The harpy must take a bonus action on its subsequent turns to continue singing.

However it does not specify whether the initial singing is also a bonus action, or if it is the harpy's entire action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The harpy's initial *Luring Song* is an action not a bonus action, as it's under the **Actions** section of its stat block, the same as everything else.

From page 10 of the MM:

> When a monster takes its *action*, it can choose from the options in the Actions section of its stat block...

Until the harpy stops singing, it can use its bonus action to continue singing. After the harpy stops singing, it must use its action to start again.